# My sfml code can't find / load any sprite. Why?

Tags: c++, sfml

I have this SFML c++ code that is supposed to load a sprite from a file:

```
Texture TankTexture;
Sprite tank;

std::string path = "tank.png";
TankTexture.loadFromFile(path);
tank.setTexture(TankTexture);
```

But it gives me an error after I run the code and crashes my app with a bunch of random characters in the terminal. I have also tried with other images and it doesn't work. I made sure that the sprite is in the same folder as the .cpp file. Still doesn't work. Any ideas[image]?

Here is the mumbo jumbo the console gives me: [image]

Comment: Try giving it an absolute path which I'm sure will work then check to see what directory the application is starting up in (probably the Debug folder) and make sure the image is accessible from there.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I tried giving it "E:/SFML/Fights/Fights/tank.png" which is the same directory that I screenshotted, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a file extension in your screenshot. Make sure the path in the SFML code is absolute or relative: "./tank.png", and that the file you have saved actually matches that path. (there is no .png in screenshot)

Also using when using SFML its good practice to validate if a texture is loaded or not:

```
if(!texture.loadFromFile("./tank.png")){
    std::cout << "[ERR] could not load image!"
    exit(1)
}
```

If something went wrong and the texture wasn't loaded (ie the image wasn't there), we exit the program.